# Array values being overwritten in gawk

Tags: multidimensional-array, awk, associative-array, gawk

**Sample of File I'm reading in**

```
011084,31.0581,-87.0547,  25.9 AL BREWTON 3 SSE     
012813,30.5467,-87.8808,   7.0 AL FAIRHOPE 2 NE     
013160,32.8347,-88.1342,  38.1 AL GAINESVILLE LOCK     
013511,32.7017,-87.5808,  67.1 AL GREENSBORO     
013816,31.8700,-86.2542, 132.0 AL HIGHLAND HOME     
015749,34.7442,-87.5997, 164.6 AL MUSCLE SHOALS AP     
017157,34.1736,-86.8133, 243.8 AL SAINT BERNARD     
017304,34.6736,-86.0536, 187.5 AL SCOTTSBORO
```

**GAWK Code**

```
#!/bin/gawk

BEGIN{
FS=",";
OFS=",";
}

{
print $1,$2,$3,$4
station=""$1 #Forces to be string

#Save latitude 
stationInfo[station][lat]=$2
print "lat",stationInfo[station][lat]

#Save longitude
stationInfo[station][lon]=$3
print "lon",stationInfo[station][lon]

#Now try printing the latitude again
#It will return the value of the longitude instead
print "lat",stationInfo[station][lat]

print "---------------"
}
```

**Sample output**

```
011084,31.0581,-87.0547,  25.9 AL BREWTON 3 SSE                  
lat,31.0581
lon,-87.0547
lat,-87.0547
---------------
012813,30.5467,-87.8808,   7.0 AL FAIRHOPE 2 NE                  
lat,30.5467
lon,-87.8808
lat,-87.8808
---------------
```

For some reason the value stored in `stationInfo[station][lat]` is being overwritten by the longitude. I'm at a loss for what in the world is going on.

I'm using GAWK 4.1.1 on Fedora 22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the fact that `lon` and `lat` are variables and evaluate to the empty string so this assignment `stationInfo[station][lat]=$2` and `stationInfo[station][lon]=$3` are assigning to `stationInfo[station]["]`.

You need to quote the `lat` and `lon` in those (and the other) lines to use strings instead of variables.

```
#!/bin/gawk

BEGIN{
    FS=",";
    OFS=",";
}

{
    print $1,$2,$3,$4
    station=""$1 #Forces to be string

    #Save latitude 
    stationInfo[station]["lat"]=$2
    print "lat",stationInfo[station]["lat"]

    #Save longitude
    stationInfo[station]["lon"]=$3
    print "lon",stationInfo[station]["lon"]

    #Now try printing the latitude again
    #It will return the value of the longitude instead
    print "lat",stationInfo[station]["lat"]

    print "---------------"
}
```

Comment: Damn, I thought I already tried that. But I did it just now and it works. Thanks!